# After updating to MacOS Catalina MAMP doesn't work anymore with root on a network mount

Tags: afp, mamp

I have a network mount on /var/www (original on /Volumes/internet, connected to afp://nasbox/). This is the document root for my MAMP server (5.5). After upgrading to MacOS Catalina I get the following error:

> [Wed Oct 09 03:56:05 2019] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] (1)Operation not
>   permitted: Can't open directory for index: /Volumes/internet/

I can connect to the network folder, I can see it's content if I check with a terminal, but MAMP doesn't seem to be able to read from it after the update. How can I make things work again?

*EDIT: I changed the DocumentRoot to a 'real' local folder (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs) and everything seems to be running as expected, which leads me to belief the mapping to the NAS is the problem. ls -l showed me I had all permissions on this drive (drwxrwxrwx)

Comment: How does MAMP access it, via /Volumes/internet or via /var/www? In the second case, is there a symlink or something to redirect to the mount point?

Comment: I tried both, /var/www is a symlink indeed to /volumes/internet. The other is a network mount

Answer (score 2):

you need to update `mkcert` on your system.

1. `brew install mkcert --HEAD`
2. `mkcert -install`

https://github.com/FiloSottile/mkcert/issues/174

Comment: updating homebrew was well needed judging by what it updated. Unfortunately this didn't fix the problem I have though. The weird thing is that I can access the folder needed from everywhere, but MAMP can't seem to read from it

Comment: patrick try to recursively change permissions to all folders inside of your localhost root folder to 775 and make sure that group is changed to "admin"

Comment: I think the problem might be Catalina. It must Grant permission to programs to read certain folders. MAMP, gimp, inkscape all need this permission, but don't ask and all these programs have this issue...

Comment: @patrick and did you find any idea on how to solve the issue?

Comment: No, I gave up and installed a separate machine with Ubuntu, Apache, etc.